# Python Google Login User Pass BeautifulSoup Post

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess

I want to login using BeautifulSoup and requests with python. Can you help me?

Webdriver ve selenium I can do with but I BeautifulSoup and requests I want to do with

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1'
}

url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login?hl=tr&continue=http://www.google.com"

login_data = {
    'id': 'username@gmail.com',
}

url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1"
with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    r = s.post(url,headers=headers)

print(r.content)
```

Comment: turn off JavaScript in browser and you will see what BS is seeing. And than try to login manually.

Comment: Can you give an example through code

Comment: First use browser without JavaScript to see if you can login. Maybe page doesn't work without JavaScript - or it sends different HTML.

Comment: Page doesn't work without JavaScript. With JavaScript it send date encrypted. I don't know what it uses to encrypt it. It doesn't look like base64. You would have to dig in JavaScript code to find out and later you would have to write the same function in Python.